# Whitney sum bundle vs. direct product bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

The question is simple: are Whitney sum bundle and direct product bundle the same? When are they different?

**PS:** I have realized my mistake: let $E_1 \to B$ and $E_2 \to B$ be two bundles, their Whitney sum is $E_1 \oplus E_2 \to B$ whereas their direct product is $E_1 \times E_2 \to B \times B$.  Although $E_1 \oplus E_2 \cong E_1 \times E_2$ their base spaces are different!

**Request:** I have flagged this question requesting to delete it.  Could some moderator help me?

Comment: It may be useful if you spelled out the definitions you are using for the two constructions.

Comment: Got it!  Sorry for mistaking the definitions!

Comment: @PhysicsMath: Note that your question was put on hold because it was unclear. Please consider editing it to clarify your question, in particular, please try to explain what you were confused about or why you were confused.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: actually that is my mistake, I forgot the difference in base space.  I have flagged this question requesting to delete it but got no reply!

Comment: You wrote in your edit that $E_1\oplus E_2\cong E_1\times E_2$, but that simply does not make any sense, as thetwo bundles are on different bases...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: but what I wrote is just direct sum and direct product of topological spaces not bundles...

Comment: There is no such thing as the direct sum of two topological spaces.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same.

Given two vector bundles  $E_1$, $E_2$ over the same base $X$, their Whitney sum is the vector bundle $E_1\oplus E_2$ over $X$.

Given a vector bundle $E$ over $X$ and a vector bundle $F$ over $Y$, their product is the vector bundle $E\times F$ over $X\times Y$. More precisely, $E\times F = p_1^*E\oplus p_2^*F$ where $p_1, p_2$ are the projections onto the first and second factors respectively.

Comment: Got it!  Sorry for mistaking the definitions!

Comment: Would it be correct to say the whitney sum of two vector bundles over a base, leads to the direct product of their structure groups?

Comment: @R. Rankin: Yes.

Comment: I've asked a somewhat related question here, you seem to be an expert https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594094/editedtangent-frame-bundle-of-a-whitney-sum-product-of-tangent-frame-bund