# (Tangent) Frame bundle of a Whitney sum $=$ product of tangent frame bundles?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have an n-dimensional parallelizable Riemannian manifold $M$ whose tangent space decomposes into a Whitney sum:

$$TM=VM\oplus HM$$ The obvious example being when $M$ is a frame bundle with a connection defined. I'd like to find the tangent frame bundle $F\left(VM\oplus HM\right)$. I'm wondering if it's as simple as:

$$F\left(VM\oplus HM\right)=F(VM)\times F(HM)$$

I'm guessing it can't be that easy? I have Kobayashi and I'm digging through it for answers.

EXAMPLE:

Suppose we have an orientable, compact Riemannian three manifold $N$ The oriented orthonormal frame bundle is then written as:

$$FN=N\times SO(3)$$

Given a set of everywhere orthonormal frames $\theta^{i}$ on $N$ we can define a metric compatible connection $d\theta^{i}=\omega_{j}^{i}\wedge\theta^{j}$. My understanding is this defines a splitting of the tangent bundle into horizontal and vertical sub-bundles:

$$T(FN)=TN\oplus T(SO(3))$$

I would like to find (tangent) orthonormal frame bundle $F(FN)$. Because $FN$ is 6-dimensional Riemannian manifold (and all frame bundles are parallellizable) we might expect:

$$F(FN)=FN\times SO(6)$$

However we have the extra structure that the set of frames $\left\{ \theta^{i},\omega^{ij}\right\}$ on the space $FN$ are not independent, so our structure group will be reduced to some sub-group of $SO(6)$. This makes sense to me if the relation:

$$F(TN\oplus T(SO(3))=FN\times F(SO(3))=FN\times SO(3)\times SO(3)$$

holds. This means that the splitting of the tangent bundle induces a reduction of the structure group (group homomorphism?) $$SO(6)\rightarrow SO(3)\times SO(3)$$

Is this correct in general (or even this case lol)?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't either, apologies, I'm from a physics background

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  ok, I have edited the question to be more applicable, this is what I meant in the first place